# Laravel/PHP Refactor code to use same different modal

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel (PHP). I want to refactor below code to ask class A and class B to use the same funsth(). funSth() is repeated in two class while the only difference is the model.

Is there a way I can simplify to below? Is that possible to refactor it into second code?

Current:

```
class A {

    public function funSth(){
        Models\Profile::create();
    }

    public function main(){
        $this->funA();
    }
}

class B {
    public function funSth(){
        Models\Location::create();
    }

    public function main(){
        $this->funB();
    }
}
```

Expected:

```
class A {
    public function main(){
        (new Y)->funSth();
    }
}

class B {
    public function main(){
        (new Y)->funSth();
    }
}

class Y {
    public function funSth(){
         Models\AnyModel::create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the below answer solve your issue or are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is to make a [Trait](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Traits essentially allow you to use the same code in multiple classes.

Base on the code in your question, your trait would look something like:

```php
trait Y 
{
    public function funSth()
    {
         Models\AnyModel::create();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the correct namespace for the file.

Then in your other classes you would have the use the `use` keyword inside the class body:

```php
class A 
{
    use Y;

    public function main()
    {
        $this->funA();
    }
}
```

If you're trait is in a different namespace then you'll need to either give the full class name with the namespace or [import](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) the trait into your class.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for ur answer. But the funA() is not defined in trait Y. Plus funSth() in the trait cannot create model based on the Class A and Class B.

Answer (score 0):

After researching for a while. Here is my solution.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait Y
{
    protected function create(Model $model, array $attributes){
        model->create($attributes);
    }
}
```

Therefore, for Class A and Class B:

```
class A 
{
    use Y;

    public function main($data){
        $this->create((new Models\ModelAA), $data)
    }
}

class B 
{
    use Y;

    public function main($data){
        $this->create((new Models\ModelBB), $data)
    }
}
```

The basic idea is to use the abstract class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` in trait Y and initialize model before it.